# hiding view till animation done android

Tags: android, animation

Hey I have a set of textView below each other in a right side navigation menu I want when the menu open to animation the `textview` from right to the left and for that I have two animation the first one is animation set which contain translate animation and alpha animation.
firstly after first animation i have a problem that the `textview` appear in its place before the animation starts and I fix it by adding `FillBefore=false` to the animations in animation set and setting the `textview` visibility to invisible before the animation start
and that was working fine.

then I wanted to add another animation after the first animation set is finished and when I added this animation the problem came back and I cant resolve, I remove the second animation  it works again

here's my animation set

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillEnabled="false"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="150%"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

and the animation listener for animation set is

```
       main_set = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.main_menu);
    main_set.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
           // main_dashboard_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            main_dashboard_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            main_dashboard_txt.startAnimation(allanim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

and the all anim animation is

```
   final TranslateAnimation allanim = new TranslateAnimation(0, pxFromDp(getActivity(), 21), 0, 0);
    allanim.setDuration(100);
    allanim.setFillAfter(true);
    allanim.setFillBefore(false);
    allanim.setFillEnabled(true);
    allanim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           // main_dashboard_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

I have changed the value of fill before and fill after many times but they seems doesn't works on the second animation

ALSO: it works fine for first time I open the activity but when I close the drawer and then reopen it the problem happens
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by setting `Fillafter = false` and `FillBefore=true` and onAnimationEnd I set the view to Visible Again
The problem was if Fill after equal true the view stay on the screen even if I set its visibility to invisible

Answer (score 1):

Put the View to be hidden in another Thread or Runnable  to be invisible for the duration of the Animation

Comment: Thx Man but i fixed my problem finally the problem was with fill before and fill after i was using them in wrong way